# repeated if_else with dates to make variable "Enddate" not working

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm quite new to R. So I'm probably not aware of any other solutions to my problem.
I need to make a variable "enddate", which is the date a study ended for someone in my dataset. It is the time that they were diagnosed with an illness. This variable needs to be build from 50 variables (25 for if they were diagnosed with an illness when they visited the General Practicioner (GP) (1= severe illness, 2=mild illness, 3=healthy) and the 25 corresponding dates of the visits). Of course, not every person went to the GP 25 times, e.g. some went only twice and some 18. If they were never diagnosed, the enddate is the last date they visited the GP. Also, people could be diagnosed before the startdate. Those people are still included in the study. So enddate is the date of the GP visit they were diagnosed after the start of the study.

Some example data:

| ID | Startdate | DiaGP1 | DateGP1 | DiaGP2 | DateGP2 | DiaGP3 | DateGP3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02-04-2006 | 3 | 05-03-2006 | 1 | 07-09-2007 | 1 | 29-01-2009 |
| 2 | 05-07-2008 | 1 | 11-04-2006 | 3 | 17-02-2010 | 1 | 15-01-2011 |
| 3 | 05-07-2008 | 3 | 05-03-2009 | 1 | 09-02-2010 | 3 | 14-12-2012 |
| 4 | 31-04-2007 | 3 | 16-11-2010 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I tried an if_else with two conditions.

```
Data$enddate <- if_else(Data$DiaGP1 == 1 & Data$DateGP1 > Data$Startdate, Data$DateGP1, if_else(Data$DiaGP1 == 2 & Data$DateGP1 > Data$Startdate, Data$DateGP1, if_else(Data$DiaGP2 == 1 & Data$DateGP2 > Data$Startdate, Data$DateGP2, if_else(Data$DiaGP2 == 2 & Data$DateGP2 > Data$Startdate, Data$DateGP2, if_else(Data$DiaGP3 == 1 & Data$DateGP3 > Data$Startdate, Data$DateGP3, if_else(Data$DiaGP3 == 2 & Data$DateGP3 > Data$Startdate, Data$DateGP3, NA))))))
```

My original plan was to keep the cell empty if they never were diagnosed with an illness, because I need to have an overview of how many people were diagnosed. My plan was to make a separate line to fill the cells with NA's in later.

I get a "+" when I run the code and nothing happens.

I hope there is a way that makes more sense than this. Or maybe someone has some advice on how to make this work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you accessing your variables without the subset operator (`$`)?

Comment: No I do use $ to access them.

Comment: But in your `if_else` call you have, for instance, `DiaGP1` instead of `Data$DiaGP1`.

Comment: Yep, I do have that in my script, but I forgot to add that to the example. I added it, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: The error you’re getting arises when you try to assign a vector of incompatible length to a data.frame. This shouldn’t be the case given your code example, but, if your script is different from what we see here, it could be the case. You may check the length of the result of both sides of your `<-` operation to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated

After your comment, I realized I missed a major element of your question. Sorry about that.

This update gives you the end date which is the minimum date if the prognosis is either 1 or 2 by ID.
If all dates by ID have prognosis 3, the maximum date is the end date.

> I wasn't sure how you wanted to handle the case where they were 1, then 3, then 1. Currently, it's going to give you the date for that initial prognosis of 1. If you want something different, you'll have to explain what you are looking for. (See row 3 in your example data.)

I added to the example data you provided so that I could test all of the test cases. This code starts with the example data I used to test.

```
dt <- read.table(header = T, text = "
                 ID Startdate   DiaGP1  DateGP1 DiaGP2  DateGP2 DiaGP3  DateGP3
1   02-04-2006  3   05-03-2006  1   07-09-2007  1   29-01-2009
2   05-07-2008  1   11-04-2006  3   17-02-2010  1   15-01-2011
3   05-07-2008  3   05-03-2009  1   09-02-2010  3   14-12-2012
4   31-04-2007  3   16-11-2010  NA  NA  NA  NA")

# add more rows for test cases
dt <- as.data.frame(rbind(dt, dt))
dt[5, c(3, 5, 7)] <- 3
dt[6, c(3, 5, 7)] <- 1
dt[ , 1] <- 1:8
dt # looks as expected
```

This approach sets all dates to a date type, then pivots the data, so all dates and prognoses are placed into two respective columns. After grouping by ID, 3 cases are tested to determine the date that needs to be used for the ID: all prognoses are 3; no prognoses are 3, and neither of these. Because there are NAs, `na.rm` is added to all applicable functions in these test cases. You'll see several warnings because of the numerous tests that have no NA values. Once an end date has been assigned to each ID, the data is pivoted back to the original format and organized by ID. I added `as.data.frame()` because I'm just not a fan of the way `tibble` truncates everything. However, you don't need that last function.

```
dt %>% mutate(across(contains("date"), dmy)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !c(ID, Startdate), 
               names_to = c(".value", "event"),
               names_sep = "G") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(endDate = case_when(
    all(Dia == 3, na.rm = T) ~ max(Date, na.rm = T),
    all(Dia != 3, na.rm = T) ~ min(Date, na.rm = T),
    TRUE ~ min(Date[Dia != 3], na.rm = T))
  ) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, Startdate, endDate),
                    names_from = event,
                    values_from = c(Dia, Date),
                    names_sep = "G",
                    names_vary = "slowest") %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>% as.data.frame()
#   ID  Startdate    endDate DiaGP1    DateGP1 DiaGP2    DateGP2 DiaGP3    DateGP3
# 1  1 2006-04-02 2007-09-07      3 2006-03-05      1 2007-09-07      1 2009-01-29
# 2  2 2008-07-05 2006-04-11      1 2006-04-11      3 2010-02-17      1 2011-01-15
# 3  3 2008-07-05 2010-02-09      3 2009-03-05      1 2010-02-09      3 2012-12-14
# 4  4       <NA> 2010-11-16      3 2010-11-16     NA       <NA>     NA       <NA>
# 5  5 2006-04-02 2009-01-29      3 2006-03-05      3 2007-09-07      3 2009-01-29
# 6  6 2008-07-05 2006-04-11      1 2006-04-11      1 2010-02-17      1 2011-01-15
# 7  7 2008-07-05 2010-02-09      3 2009-03-05      1 2010-02-09      3 2012-12-14
# 8  8       <NA> 2010-11-16      3 2010-11-16     NA       <NA>     NA       <NA>
```

`endDate` ends up in column 3. If you wanted the `endDate` field to be the last column, just add `%>% select(everything(), endDate)`

If you want to suppress warnings, like those shouting at you for this code, you can use the following:

```
# for a temporary silence add before code
w <- getOption("warn") 
options(warn = -1) 

# to receive warnings again add after code
options(warn = w)
```

If I've missed something else, let me know.

---

---

##### Originally wrote ----

I used the libraries `lubridate` and `tidyverse`. To make this easier than identifying each column by name or index, I looked for a column name pattern that would allow me to find all of the columns with a date in them.

I used this information to parse the dates into date-type and find the max date per row.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dt <- read.table(header = T, text = "
                 ID Startdate   DiaGP1  DateGP1 DiaGP2  DateGP2 DiaGP3  DateGP3
1   02-04-2006  3   05-03-2006  1   07-09-2007  1   29-01-2009
2   05-07-2008  1   11-04-2006  3   17-02-2010  1   15-01-2011
3   05-07-2008  3   05-03-2009  1   09-02-2010  3   14-12-2012
4   31-04-2007  3   16-11-2010  NA  NA  NA  NA")


dt %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("date"), dmy),              # change data type to date
         endDate = max(c_across(contains("date")), na.rm = T)) # find max date
# # A tibble: 4 × 9
# # Rowwise: 
#      ID Startdate  DiaGP1 DateGP1    DiaGP2 DateGP2    DiaGP3 DateGP3    endDate   
#   <int> <date>      <int> <date>      <int> <date>      <int> <date>     <date>    
# 1     1 2006-04-02      3 2006-03-05      1 2007-09-07      1 2009-01-29 2009-01-29
# 2     2 2008-07-05      1 2006-04-11      3 2010-02-17      1 2011-01-15 2011-01-15
# 3     3 2008-07-05      3 2009-03-05      1 2010-02-09      3 2012-12-14 2012-12-14
# 4     4 NA              3 2010-11-16     NA NA             NA NA         2010-11-16
```

There's no April 31st, so that ends up as NA.

Comment: Thank you. However, how do I set the enddate as DateGP2 for person 1 and 3? As these dates would be their enddate because they are diagnosed with an illness?

Comment: Sometimes I can't help but get in my own way! I'm sorry about that. I've updated my answer...hopefully, this **really** answers your question.

Comment: Hi Kat, thank you for all the effort. One thing is still missing. It is a requirement that the enddate is after the startdate. For example, the enddate for participant 2 is DateGP3. Would you have any tips on how to include this?

Comment: Is the requirement 'the first trigger after the start date'? Or is the requirement the last trigger if alternating between 3 and not 3? or both? Shouldn't all GP dates be after the start date? (Is this dirty data or something you need to account for?)